# Expectation over sequencial random shuffles

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to understand this concept with this following problem:

> Logan is cleaning his apartment. In particular, he must sort his old
> favorite sequence, , of  positive integers in nondecreasing order.
> He's tired from a long day, so he invented an easy way (in his
> opinion) to do this job. His algorithm can be described by the
> following pseudocode:
>
> ```
> while isNotSorted(P) do {   
>     WaitOneMinute();
>     RandomShuffle(P)
> }
> ```
>
> Can you determine the expected number of minutes that Logan will spend
> waiting for  to be sorted?

*Let's say we need to evaluate this situation:*

array with 2 items:

> 5,2

**Solution:**

> There are two permutations possible after a random shuffle, and each
> of them has probability . The probability to get the sequence sorted
> after the first minute is . The probability that  will be sorted after
> the second minute is , the probability  will be sorted after the third
> minute is , and so on. So, the answer is equal to the following sum:
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i*2^{-i} = 2.000000$

I understand that this is an expectation problem.

But I can't get the correct situation for a list different of 2 as size. As explained above

**Can some one explain me what happens with 3 as size of the list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose he must sort the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

If $\mu$ denotes the expected number of minutes then:
$$\mu=\frac1{n!}1+(1-\frac1{n!})(1+\mu)$$

Here $\frac1{n!}$ is the probability that he is ready after one minute.

If he is not then he must start over again and has lost one minute.

This equality tells us that : $$\mu=n!$$

More formally:

If $E$ denotes the event that he succeeds in one minute then:

$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(X\mid E)P(E)+\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)P(E^c)$$
and this with $$\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)=1+\mathbb EX$$

Comment: thanks, it explained a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're all distinct, the process succeeds with probability $1$ divided by the number of possible permutations, which is $n!$ for a sequence of $n$ positive integers. So it takes $n!$ steps on average.

Comment: what about the conditional probabilities? why the prob. of the first minute will be different of the second?

btw You are right... my algorithm just worked with your point...

Comment: @AlvaroJoao It's because they're not different, you just pick a completely random shuffle and could potentially see the same shuffle multiple times. It'd be a bit faster if you avoided repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $n$ distinct items are ordered  in the favorite order after one minute is

$\frac1{n!}$

The probability that $n$ distinct items are ordered in the favorite order after k minutes is

$P(X=k)=\frac1{n!}\cdot \left(1-\frac1{n!} \right)^{k-1}$

The expected value is related to the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot P(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot  \frac1{n!}\cdot \left(1-\frac1{n!} \right)^{k-1}=n!$$